# How to replace this url to my a format id that i want, thanks

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there any way (maybe a regex) to replace the id dynamic to "id"
I use js and typescript
The original url:

```
localhost:4200/reservations/5eda023aed43c1e46d6ce804/properties/5ca199fdda8ba619695b5728
```

The url i want:

```
localhost:4200/reservations/id/properties/id
```

Comment: If the url will always be `localhost:4200/reservations/id/properties/id`, then there's no need to do any replacing.

Comment: @RichieBendall i want to replace 5eda023aed43c1e46d6ce804 become id sir

Comment: Are you trying to insert ids into the `id` slots in `localhost:4200/reservations/id/properties/id`?

Comment: nope sir, i just want to change a url with specify id like `5eda023aed43c1e46d6ce804` and  `5ca199fdda8ba619695b5728` become a url with general id

Comment: i was tried some regex but there is none works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```js
let url = 'localhost:4200/reservations/5eda023aed43c1e46d6ce804/properties/5ca199fdda8ba619695b5728';
let replacedUrl = url.replace(/\/[a-fA-F0-9]{24}/g, "/id");
console.log(replacedUrl);
```

Comment: it's not works with me bro!

Comment: I edited, try the full code now.
Is it not working with this url for you?
or with another url?

Comment: yeah it's good now bro, perfectly.So many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using regex:

```js
function replaceURL(url, data) {
  Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => url = url.replace(new RegExp(`(?<=${key}\\/)\\w+`, 'g'), value));
  return url;
}

// the original url
const url = 'localhost:4200/reservations/5eda023aed43c1e46d6ce804/properties/5ca199fdda8ba619695b5728';

// put what you want to replace in this object
const data = {
  reservations: 'id',
  properties: 'id'
};

const result = replaceURL(url, data);
console.log(result);
```

### Edit

I think I overthought the situation, if you just want to replace the text similar to `5eda023aed43c1e46d6ce804`, you can just use the following regex:

```js
/(?<=\/)[0-9a-f]{24,}/g
```

```js
const regex = /(?<=\/)[0-9a-f]{24,}/g;

let url = 'localhost:4200/reservations/5eda023aed43c1e46d6ce804/properties/5ca199fdda8ba619695b5728';
let result = url.replace(regex, 'id');
console.log(result);

url = 'http://localhost:4200/minibar/items/5efdcee02c37c160e8a5bbe1';
result = url.replace(regex, 'id');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: it so good bro, but it dont work for other url like `http://localhost:4200/minibar/items/5efdcee02c37c160e8a5bbe1`
Is there a way generality to i can use with any url.So many thanks bro

Comment: It works, just make the `data = { items: 'id' }`

Comment: The key names of the object correspond to the url path name, you have to make them identical.

Answer (score 1):

If your url format is fix then you can use this simple code.

```js
var link=" localhost:4200/reservations/5eda023aed43c1e46d6ce804/properties/5ca199fdda8ba619695b5728";
//var link="http://localhost:4200/minibar/items/5efdcee02c37c160e8a5bbe1"
var hasNumber = /\d/; 
var linkParts=link.split("/");
var i=link.indexOf("http")==0?3:2;
for(i;i<linkParts.length;i++)
{
  if(linkParts[i].length>20 && hasNumber.test(linkParts[i]))
    linkParts[i]="id";
}
document.write(linkParts.join("/"));
```

Comment: actually, it's so many url with difference format, it good but not work with another url i have like `http://localhost:4200/minibar/items/5efdcee02c37c160e8a5bbe1`
bro, is there anything way to automatic replace.Btw thanks

Comment: If you have many different URL  then you can split URL by "/" , then loop return array from index 3 (e.g. for i=3 to array.length) ,and check if any part of URL contains  number and check its length too and replace with "id" , again join your final array with "/". may this will work for your all URL.

Comment: @DuongTran  check my updated code this may help you.

Comment: it's works bro.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace the exact `id` with what you want.

```js
let url = 'localhost:4200/reservations/5eda023aed43c1e46d6ce804/properties/5ca199fdda8ba619695b5728';
let id = '5eda023aed43c1e46d6ce804' // the id to replace

let rx = new RegExp(id,"g"); // use "g" to indicate it should should ALL ids in the string
url = url.replace(rx, "id") // this will replace the dynamic id with the word "id"

// localhost:4200/reservations/id/properties/id
```